# maven/pom build error due to SSL issue/corp Non-resolvable parent POM

Tags: maven, ssl, pom.xml

I am facing below :

Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX .Failure to transfer org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.1.8.RELEASE from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.1.8.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): proxy.example.com and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POMJava(0)

I am on corp/work network, using visual studio code for a basic Springboot project.

How can I make it work?

What I tried?

used the working pom file for another  project,It works as expected. (However this has corp internal repositories)
I also tried importing the ssl certs for this "https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2", howevever i don't have permissions to do that, since I am using Enterprise machine.
Also I did try many other solutions(tweaking the pom) suggested here, but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: This is an issue that you should resolve inside your company. Many companies make repositories like MavenCentral available through their own repository managers like Nexus or Artifactory. If you need direct access to an internet resource, you probably have to talk to your network administrator.

Comment: yeah...i went ahead and added  the relevant repositories and seems to be working so far.